# PXE TFTP Permission Denied

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, tftp

I have a windows server 2003 VM and since Virtualbox supports NAT networking and has the Intel PXE firmware, id like to test it out and maybe use it between two real machines in the future.

I have created and started the Microsoft windows TFTP service on the VM and it is set to run automatically, I have set the path for the service to look in C:/TFTP, the folder exists too.
I have granted the folder permissions to full access to 'owner' 'anonymous' and 'system'

I can FTP to it fine in the VM and I have the folder to accept anonymous Logons, I have set it to only allow 1 connection at a time.

I cant seem to locate the .pxe image, apparently its in the same folder as virtualbox.xml but I cant find that either. (on the host)

Virtualbox is saying that it cant access the .pxe image over TFTP

My firewalls are turned off on the host and the VM., if I use tftp.exe it cant find a text file which is in C:/tftp
Tftp help says it can use local and remote hosts for file transfers.

I don't know how to resolve this, iv'e googled around but nothing.

Comment: "I cant seem to locate the .pxe image, apparently its in the same folder as virtualbox.xml but I cant find that either. (on the host)" It sounds like you're confused... you _put_ a pxe file in the same folder as virtualbox.xml for VirtualBox's NAT to serve to the VMs. But you've set up your own TFTP server so presumably you don't want to use VirtualBox's NAT?

Comment: Ok yes Im confused, I want to use the VM as the server and connect to the same VM just as a first test to see if it works.

Comment: Okay. At the risk of stating the obvious, if the virtual machine running the TFTP server is using VirtualBox NAT, you'll need to port forward the appropriate ports for TFTP (UDP/69 and TCP/8099) if you want things outside to be able to connect to it. You can do that with the Settings -> Network -> Port Forwarding button, and then add a row for each port, with the same host and guest ports, and you normally don't have to fill in the Guest IP.

Comment: I have port fprwarded the NAT now, but the error is still the same
Here is the NAT config http://oi58.tinypic.com/2pp0qww.jpg

and Here is the full PXE error screen:http://oi58.tinypic.com/317i1kp.jpg

in regedit the directory for tftp is C:/TFTP and must be set under hklm/system/currentcontrolset/services/tftpdsvc/paramaters .

Comment: You mentioned just using tftp.exe to test the tftp server; if you do that from a different VM and attempt to get that same "windows xp server edition.pxe" file does it get the same error?

Comment: The other VM does not have internet connection and is looking for the pxe image for that vm name anyway